# Number of components in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

In $G$ between every two vertices exists at most 1 path. If $G$ has $2017$ vertices and $1920$ edges. How many components does $G$ have?

I don't even know how to think about this one. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a single answer, as you have given the question ("between every two vertices exists at most 1 edge"), but there is a range of possible answers.

The key limits are that a tree has the fewest number of edges compared to vertices: $n{-}1$ edges in a tree with $n$ vertices - meaning each tree uses one more vertex than edge from target count, so a forest of tree graphs would have the fewest components.

And a complete graph, $K_n$, has $n(n-1)/2$ edges, so there are enough edges for a $K_{64}$ with one to spare - meaning you could use all the edges with $65$ vertices and leave the remaining vertices isolated (and so each of them components).

As the question has been amended so that between any two vertices there is at most one *path*, the answer is to make the graph from trees, since they have no cycles and hence only single paths between vertices. Thus for each tree component of the graph there will be one fewer edge than vertices used. And over the whole graph we need to have $2017-1920=97$ fewer edges than vertices.

Comment: How am i supposed to know exact number of components? For example, there can be 97 components, that is if tree has 1921 vertices. But for sure, there can be trees of smaller size?

Comment: Suppose you have 20 trees with 20 vertices and 77 trees with 21 vertices. What does that give you?

Comment: Should've thought about that. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that an isolated vertex in fact meets the criteria for a tree (a seed, perhaps?) so one tree of 1921 vertices and the remaining 96 vertices isolated also falls under this category.

Comment: Yes, that was my blind spot